# Как сделать чтоб при нажатии на клавиатуре телефона "Enter" она срабатывала правильно?

Tags: java, android

Суть такая, у меня приложение ждет ввода с клавиатуры, и когда на клавиатуре нажимаем "Enter" то просто переключается строка. Как програмно получить доступ к этой кнопке и задать ей функции которые она будет выполнять при нажатии?

Comment: Ну а обычный вариант с OnKeyListener чем не устраивает? В методе: `public boolean onKey(View v, int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {if (event.getAction() == KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN && (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_ENTER)) { return true;} return false;}`   ссылка http://developer.android.com/intl/ru/reference/android/view/View.OnKeyListener.html

Comment: @VolhaGomel, вы бы это в качестве ответа написали...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Стандартно,чтобы обработать нажатие клавиш виртуальной клавиатуры необходимо реализовать интерфейс OnKeyListener, а затем назначить его для нужного view, c помощью setOnKeyListener.

К примеру, на нажатие на edittext1 будет будут реагировать клавиши клавиатуры:

```
edittext1.setOnKeyListener(new OnKeyListener() {
public boolean onKey(View v, int keyCode, KeyEvent event)
{
}
});
```

Далее можно использовать параметр keyCode, чтобы определить, какая клавиши была нажата:

```
public boolean onKey(View view, int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
    if (event.getAction() == KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN &&
                (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_ENTER))
    {              
//тут пишем какие-то условия если клавиша ввод на клав. нажата 
return true;
    }
return false;
}//close onKey
```

Comment: Я выполнил имплеминтацию OnKeyListener, переопределил 3 метода и пытаюсь прицепить на  edittext `setOnKeyListener()` но мне показывает ошибку что не может распознать этот метод...

Comment: если именно имплеминтировали, то нужно написать так: `edittext1.setOnKeyListener(this);`